# Rails can't find asset after page reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, ruby-on-rails-3.2, passenger

I face a problem with a rails (3.2.6)  application on our production server (nginx + passenger 3). After a

```
rake assets:precompile
```

one static page works like a charm but after a few minutes I receive an asset not found error for an existing image. If I recompile the assets again it works but a few minutes later rails raise the file-not-found error again.

Here you can see production.rb and Gemfile: https://gist.github.com/3937589

Answer (score 0):

- Is there any way that your code is doing any manipulation of the /public folder?
- Have you verified that the asset in question is indeed in the /public folder?
- Are there cron jobs or other processes at work that maybe interfere with your file system?

What the assets:precompile does is simply work through your app/assets and copies these over to `/public/assets`.

It does so normally in 3 favors: uncompressed original file, original-file + hash that gets used when referenced from a helper (`asset_path`) and the gzipped file.

You can simply go to your production server and look into `/public/assets` to verify if anything is missing. If the file is there and the user still gets errors I'd look at my nginx configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I've reconfigured nginx to serve the static assets through an location statement and now it's working.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Btw welcome to SO. 
It's customary to give an upvote to answers that you found helpful and if the answer did indeed solve or help solve the problem it should be marked as accepted.

Comment: I know but the problem occured again one hour ago, so the answer was helpful but not the solution. It seems like it's enough to restart passenger and rails recognize the image again.